# In Rake, why is CLEAN empty in my rakefile?

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm trying to add things to the CLEAN constant in my rakefile, but

```
CLEAN << 'build/sources/android_src/App/build/outputs/apk/**/*'
```

isn't working, and when I print it - even before messing with it - it's empty!

My rakefile starts like this:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/clean'
p [ CLEAN , __LINE__, __FILE__ ]
```

I've edited the library file defining CLEAN to print it immediately after definition (~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/clean.rb):

```
CLEAN = ::Rake::FileList["**/*~", "**/*.bak", "**/core"]
p [ CLEAN , __LINE__, __FILE__ ]
```

But when I run, only see a populated 'CLEAN' from the library print line, not  from my rakefile's output:

```
$ bundle exec rake android:build_bum -- --obfuscate --filters='features'
[["build/sources/android_src/App/build/generated/source/r/debug/com/boo/libraries/features/core",...], 62, "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/clean.rb"]
[[], 3, "~/git/bum/rakefile"]
...
Expected 0 apks in build/sources/android_src/App/build/outputs/apk, found 1: ["build/sources/android_src/App/build/outputs/apk/App-debug.apk"]
```

Does Rake's 'CLEAN' need to be qualified somehow? Is there a way to get some sort of definitiive absolute path for a variable?

Comment: http://www.virtuouscode.com/2014/04/28/rake-part-6-clean-and-clobber/

Comment: @CodeGnome Thanks for the link, but it doesn't really explain why CLEAN is set in clean.rb, but empty in the rakefile.